# How to group multiple buttons on mobile

Tags: buttons, layout, icons, actions

I'm working on a game website for desktop and mobile and one of the pages has 5 action buttons:

1. Edit (no text, just pencil icon)
2. Share (no text, just standard share icon)
3. Play (just text)
4. Compare scores (just text)
5. View scores (just text)

#### Desktop

[image: Desktop]

#### Mobile

[image: Mobile]

It's currently a visual mess. On top of that, I'm having a hard time making room for this number of buttons on mobile, especially if they all end up being text only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I will give an improved answer later. But in Desktop you could remove the A-Z list since it is usually not used in computers. That could free some room and improve alignment.

Comment: Can you also give us a brief of the game? Where does the "back arrow" next do "Favorite Names" will lead the user?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion - looking forward to hearing what else you have in mind. It's a list ranking website (in this case, baby names). The back button will take the user to a page with their other lists (boys names, girls names, etc.)

Comment: So the target user is: “Parents planning to/about to have a baby”?

Comment: Yup. But the website can be used to rank anything really - pet names, vacation destinations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the biggest problem with your draft is not the quantity of buttons, actually this is easily solvable on practically any screen size. In my understanding the most serious problem is in the design itself or if this is just a scheme, in how it's solved.

According to the description, there are five buttons, but the diagram shows five different entities with few elements in common to visually unify them, where long/short text mixes with icons and button design.

One of the basic points for interface design is the graphical systematization of elements with similar functionality. The first step is undoubtedly to **Unify Criteria of Graphic Representation**, either by size, color, type, content, etc.

[image: examples]

Being a game website I would not hesitate to use a kind of "gaming" interface. Here a very practical example of grouping buttons from [Callmenick](https://github.com/callmenick/CSS-Circle-Menu)

[image]

[Demo](http://aqiglobal.org/mobile/)

Comment: Oh wow this is super helpful, thanks! I considered that gaming interface as a possibility - I will definitely explore all these options and see what looks and feels best!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest grouping everything related to score under a menu with an icon like this:
[image]